# select several columns in the same moment with maximum number of missing value

Tags: r, variables, missing-data

I would like to make multiple column selections in a data-frame with a lot of columns in function of the number of missing values. The purpose is to select the column with a maximum of 10% missing value to understand which variable I have to select for multiple imputations of missing value.

I hade tried in this way using the *randompreop* dataset

Calculate the missing values per each column

```
oneD<-data.frame(sapply(randompreop, function(x) sum(is.na  (x)) ))

Select the column with less then 10 missing values 

nn<-c(rownames(subset(oneD, sapply.randompreop..function.x..sum.is.na.x...<=10)))
```

Then subset the initial dataset selecting the columns from the list nn

```
N<-subset(randompreop, select=c(nn))
ncol(N)
```

This code is working but do you know some much more easy code to do that?

thank you
Matteo

Answer (score 1):

As I understand your question: you would like to drop columns from your dataset if they have too many NAs. This line of code will tell you how many NAs are in each column:

```
nas_per_col <- sapply(your_dataset, function(x) sum(is.na(x)))
```

Then you can subset your dataset to just those columns with, say, less than 10 NAs by:

```
your_dataset[ , nas_per_col < 10]
```